# AJAX login lost after a update page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have autorized user from AJAX, check result and return this to client

```
if ($request->ajax()) {
    $params = $request->input('params');
} else exit();

$result = \Auth::attempt([
    'username' => $params['login'],
    'password' => $params['password']
], $params['remember']);
if (\Auth::user()) $result = 'Log in';
else $result = 'Not log in';

echo json_encode($result);
```

If everything is correct, then result is true. If I enter login or password not correctly, then browser displays: "Not log in".

But after update page user not autorized... This is my user's model:

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {
    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $hidden = ['id', 'password', 'remember_token'];
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password'];        
}
```

Comment: Please post the headers that you receive on the client with the response.

Comment: @Bogdan, this is what you need?

Connection: "Keep-Alive"
Content-Length: "34"
Content-Type: "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
Keep-Alive: "timeout=10, max=98"
Server: "Apache/2.4.10 (Win32)"